# Remote device by smartphone android

Tags: remote-access

I'm a newbie in this world.
I wanna build an application to remove some device.
Ex:
I wanna turn on or off lights and use my smartphone (Android) to do.

But, I don't know how to do? Can you show me all of steps?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Raspberry Pi (runs linux).

You can have the RPi general purpose I/O lines to control, say, relays for lights etc. and then use the many Android apps to remotely control it.